# Erro ao apresentar retorno de banco em MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Galera, estou fazendo um sistema de login em PDO não entendo muito, mas estou passando por esse problema, desenvolvi o seguinte código abaixo:

```
    $select = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM conta WHERE conta = ? AND senha = ?");
    $select -> bind_param("ss", $usuario->getConta(), md5($usuario->getSenha()));
    $select ->execute();
    $result = $select->fetch();

    if($result == 1)
    {
        echo $result['codigo'];
        echo 'success';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'not_register';

    }
```

Só que o retorno do echo $result['codigo'] é sempre vazio não aparece nada.

e quando eu dou um var_dump($result) aparece o resultado de true e nada mais e quando dou um print_r($result) aparece o número 1...

Alguém tem ideia de como resolver?

Comment: Isso aí não é PDO. `bind_param()` não permite que funções sejam passadas, apenas variáveis.

Comment: E não invente sistema de senha em PHP desse jeito. Tá cheio de blog de fanfarrão ensinando usar assim, mas não tem sentido (em 2005 talvez tivesse). PHP tem funções apropriadas para isso, que são password_hash e password_verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com o manual ( http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php ), você deve usar o bind_result para dar bind nas colunas. fetch irá pôr os valores das colunas nas variáveis que foram *bindadas*.
A variável $result recebe um boolean, então se tivesse mais de um registro precisaria iterar com um while.

Ao usar ->fetch indica que você está usando o modo orientado a objetos, para pegar como array você deveria usar `mysqli_fetch_assoc( mysqli_result $result )` (https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Segue seu código modificado para ficar da forma que o manual indica para a abordagem orientada a objetos:

```
$select = $con->prepare("SELECT codigo, conta FROM conta WHERE conta = ? AND senha = ?"); 
$select->bind_param("ss", $usuario->getConta(), md5($usuario->getSenha()));
$select->execute();

$select->bind_result($codigo, $conta);  //bind nas colunas

$result = $select->fetch();

if($result)
{
    echo $codigo;       // echo $conta;
    echo 'success';
}
else
{
    echo 'not_register';
}


$select->close();
$con->close();
```

Comment: Repare que precisei mudar a sua query para passar os nomes das colunas. Teste o código e vamos nos falando por aqui se não estiver funcionando de acordo.

Comment: Ficou muito bom meu amigo! Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado

Comment: Que bom Pedro! Fico feliz! :)